# Why do I get vertical lines on my Graph when clicking on ZedGraph?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have a `ZedGraph` control in my WinForm with a `zedGraphControl1_MouseClick` Event. When I click on a Point the `FindNearestPoint` of my Pane finds the point and focuses a row in my `DataGridView`.
Now when I click on some Points this happens:

[image]

Why do these lines not disappear? All I do is click once on it, it's like if I wanted to Zoom...
Anyone else has this Problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by just disabling both vertical and horizontal zoom. Like that there are no lines nor more....